# WebKit Scale Transformation issue

Tags: css, webkit

I need help on webkit scale functionality.

I have a .css file with properties as shown :

```
@-webkit-keyframes expand 
{
  from {-webkit-transform:scale(1)}
  to {-webkit-transform:scale(1.2)}
}

.image-highlight
{
   -webkit-animation-name: expand;
   -webkit-animation-duration:0.2s;
   -webkit-animation-iteration-count:1;
   -webkit-animation-timing-function:ease;
}
```

I have a html with elements :

```
  <div id="slider">
    <img src="images/blueMarble_0.PNG" />
    <img src="images/blueMarble_1.PNG" />
    <img src="images/blueMarble_2.PNG" />
    <img src="images/blueMarble_3.PNG" />
    <img src="images/blueMarble_4.PNG" />
  </div>
```

I have a js file with a function which will animate(scale) the middle image of the array.
and I am using this jQuery statement to do the animation:

```
 `$(pic[2]).addClass('image-highlight');`
```

This jquery actually scales the image (pic[2]). But scaling happens for 0.2 secs and it scales down to original size. How can I retain the scaling even after completion of 0.2 secs? I don't want to resize it to original size. Can it be done without changing the animation duration?
Please can you help me on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you want to add to your class: `-webkit-animation-fill-mode: both`

This will cause the animation's initial keyframe to be shown immediately when your `image-highlight` class is applied *and* the final keyframe will continue to be shown after the animation finishes.

Other values you can use:

- **none** - the effects of the animation are apparent only during the defined duration of the animation. (default)
- **backwards** – the animation’s initial keyframe is applied as soon as the animation style is applied to an element. This only affects animations that have a nonzero value for -webkit-animation-delay.
- **forwards** – the animation’s final keyframe continues to apply after the final iteration of the animation completes.

`-webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards` will probably also meet your needs.